# How can I carry out compute intensive task inside a flutter plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have build a plugin which performs machine learning tasks on an image and this takes up to a minute (or event more). During this time when the plugin is working, the flutter UI freezes and the OS shows an error asking whether we should wait or just kill the app.

I got 2 problems:

1. Flutter UI hangs even though the plugin is of course async
2. The plugin doesn't allow delayed result e.g. from a coroutine (I get this error: `E/DartMessenger(15585): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted`)

Comment: You need to stay off the main platform thread (on Android, the UiThread). On Android, you can create a new thread in the plugin to perform the task. When that task completes, you need to pass the result back to Flutter by making a native->Dart method call. As you've observed, the native handler of a Dart->native method call must return immediately (having possibly kicked off a new thread), otherwise it freezes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Isolate`s, as quoted from [this medium](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a) article on isolates:

> If you have a computation to perform that’s so enormous it could
>   cause you to drop frames if it were run in the main isolate, then you
>   can use Isolate.spawn() or Flutter’s compute() function.

more info:

1. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes
2. https://youtu.be/vl_AaCgudcY

Comment: The heavy computation is carried out in the plugin, not in dart. Secondly, plugin functions are async, so they can't be used in the compute function.

Comment: One thing I can't understand that why does running heavy computation inside a plugin affect the FPS on the Flutter layer.